# How to tabulate/aggregating a total value from an array of observables using reduce/scan (in NGRX/NGXS)

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngxs

I am trying to aggregate/tabulate the results of a set of observables.  I have an array of observables that each return a number and I want to total up those results and emit that as the value.  Each time the source numbers change, I want the end result to reflect the new total.  The problem is that I am getting the previous results added to the new total.  This has to do with how I am using the reduce/scan operator.  I believe it needs to be nested inside a switchMap/mergeMap, but so far I have been unable to figure out the solution.

I mocked up a simple example. It shows how many cars are owned by all users in total. 
Initially, the count is correct, but when you add a car to a user, the new total includes the previous total.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-concat-observables-3-drfd36

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
this.carCount$ = this.users$.pipe(
  map((users: User[]): Array<Observable<number>> => {
    let requests = users.map(
      (user: User): Observable<number> => {
        return this.store.select(UserSelectors.getCarsForUser(user)).pipe(
          map((cars: Car[]): number => {
            return cars.length;
          })
        );
      }
    );
    return requests;
  }),
  flatMap((results): Observable<number> => {
    return combineLatest(results).pipe(
      take(1),
      flatMap(data => data),
      reduce((accum: number, result: number): number => {
        return accum + result;
      }, 0)
    )
  })
);
```

I think the take(1) ends up doing the same thing as Yasser was doing above by recreating the entire stream.  I think this way is a little cleaner.

I also added another stream below it (in the code) that does one level deeper in terms of retrieving observables of observables.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-concat-observables-working-1

Anyone have a cleaner, better way of doing this type of roll-up of observable results?